# Why should I use a presigned url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Why should I use presigned URLs instead of sharing the standard object URL? The s3 object is for read only access to everyone so I dont see the point to use a presigned URL, there is just the expire feature and the longer URL which makes it harder to brute-force the correct link of a file. Any other major benefits?
Thanks

Comment: The primary use case is to allow controlled access to private objects, not public objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the files are read-only and public, and you want them to be/remain read-only/public, then there is no need to add the complexity of using a pre-signed url.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Pre-signed URL's are used to grant temporary access to s3 object for a particular amount of time.

Apart from this, you can use pre-signed URL's to grant url receiver the access to upload files to s3.

However, they are used just to keep your files private & grant temporary access to them.

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/s3-example-presigned-urls.html

Comment: OK. but If I dont use upload and I will delete the read-only file by my self it is pretty much the same?!